# How to find the length of the longest line of a text file in C

Tags: c, parsing, count

I know this should be an easy function to implement. I need to parse a .txt file and put it into a 2D array. In order to initialize the 2D array, I will need to know the number of lines and the number of characters in the longest line. I believe I have a function that will give me the number of lines. I just can not seem to get my function to find the length of the longest line to work.

Here is my code so far. I know it is wrong(as it is not working).

```
    int getrow(FILE *mapfile)
{
    int chars =0 ;
    int longest = 0;
    int Hlen;

    char *line;
    char *buf;

    line = malloc(1000);                //1000 is set to be max chars in line
    line = fgets(line, 1000, mapfile);  //get first line of file

    while(line)
    {
        chars = 0;
        buf = strtok(line, " ");
        while(buf)
        {
            chars++;
            buf = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }
        (chars > longest)?(longest = chars):(longest==longest); //If the number of characters scanned is longer than previous long, save new longest line
        line = fgets(line, 1000, mapfile);
    }
    Hlen = longest;
    free(line);

    return Hlen;
}
```

The file I am parsing is:

```
            ###################
            #       #        F####################################
            #   #  E#                                            #
            #   #####         ################################## #
            #                 #                                # #
############################  #################                # #
#                                             #                # #
#       ##################                    #                # #
#                        #####                #                # #
#      ###############       #                #                # #
#      #                     #                #                # #
###################  ##########################                # #
                #L                      #                      # #
                #             #     #   ######################## #
                #             #     #                            #
                ############  #     #   ##########################
                #             #     #   #
                #             #######   #
                #             #     #   #
                #             #     #   #
                #             #     #  S#
                #########################
```

Comment: that ternary just...stinks. `longest = (chars > longest) ? chars : longest`. don't "execute code" or do assignments inside the ternary itself.

Comment: use `chars = strlen(line)` instead of yours strtok loop

Comment: So I removed the " buf = strtok(line, " "); " and the while loop below it and replaced it with chars = strlen(line)

Comment: I also changed longest = (chars > longest) ? chars : longest 
With a IF function!

Comment: `(chars > longest)?(longest = chars):(longest==longest);` ?
"if chars is greater than longest, assign value of chars to longest; else compare longest with itself and throw away the result"

Answer (score 1):

1. as pointed out by Lashane, you can use `strlen` to get the numbers of
   characters in the line.
2. remove that ternary statement. All you need to do is check whether `chars` is greater than `longest`, and if so, update `longest`.
3. No need for the `Hlen` variable. just return `longest`
4. BONUS: There's also no need to allocate memory. Think about it, you don't actually need to save a copy of the line, you just need to go through each character of the file and count the characters between newlines. You can use [fgetc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4293475/reading-c-file-line-by-line-using-fgetc) for this.